# Higher Quality of JFreeChart charts

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I want to embed a PNG of a chart which I created with JFreeChart into a PDF document. The problem here is, that the quality of the chart is very poor. My goal is to have PNGs with 300 DPI. I googled for almost an hour now but I could not find a solution.

Is there a way to export the generated charts from JFreeCharts as a PNG (or a JPEG) with 300 DPI?

Comment: how do you export the charts?

Comment: @peshkira at the moment with  ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("/Users/myuser/test.png"),demo.getChart(),1000,1000); But of course I am open to any suggestion which works with my requirements :)

Comment: Just save it at a bigger size? 1000x1000 should give you 300dpi for a 3in x 3 in image.

Comment: Saving with more pixels results in smaller fonts. So it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.4, [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) uses the `png` encoder provided by [`ImageIO`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). As an alternative , you might look at [`com.keypoint.PngEncoder`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/com/keypoint/PngEncoder.html), which includes `setDpi()`, *et al*. See also [`org.jfree.chart.encoders.SunPNGEncoderAdapter`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/encoders/SunPNGEncoderAdapter.html) and [`org.jfree.chart.encoders.KeypointPNGEncoderAdapter`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/encoders/KeypointPNGEncoderAdapter.html).

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities#writeScaledChartAsPNG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html#writeScaledChartAsPNG%28java.io.OutputStream,%20org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

If you provide a scale factor of 2, your chart will be rendered at twice the resolution.

Comment: Using a scale factor of 2 reduces the font size by 2. So it's not a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XChart](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart) for this, as exporting `Charts` in high-res at a certain DPI is a new feature since [version 2.2.0](http://xeiam.com/xchart_changelog.jsp). The code would look something like this:

```
double[] xData = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };
double[] yData = new double[] { 2.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

// Create Chart
Chart chart = QuickChart.getChart("Sample Chart", "X", "Y", "y(x)", xData, yData);

// Show it
new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart();

// Save it
BitmapEncoder.savePNG(chart, "./Sample_Chart.png"); // default 72 DPI
BitmapEncoder.savePNGWithDPI(chart, "./Sample_Chart_300_DPI.png", 300);
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of XChart. I recently faced the exact same problem as you. I needed charts at 300 DPI for a scientific publication. Feedback is welcome!

Comment: Thanks herrtim, XCharts looks awesome. I will definitely consider using it for my next projects.